# Native command to get cpu usage by core

Tags: debian, cpu-usage, system-monitoring

Is there any simple way to get CPU usage of each core in Debian in command line? I need it to be able to output current usage into `stdout`, not like `htop` (ain't even native!), that does not have non-interactive mode at all... or dose it?

Seems like `top` can display individual cores when hitting `1` in interactive mode... but I can't find any switch for that, where in `batch` mode... (`-b`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's installed by default, but [sysstat](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sysstat) is a tool that provides a lot of system resource usage data, including CPU usage by core.  Be sure to read the [associated man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sar.1.html) for details on how to get the specific data you're looking for.

I imagine you'll end up with something along the lines of:

```
sar -P ALL 2 5
```

Comment: I can't install anything on the server, so this is not the answer for me, sorry.